# Horizontal bar graph with pgfplot and equal sized ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

When I use xbar and data to display a progress bar for some kind of data I could not find any information how it is possible to equal the space between each data line over more than one chart.

**My question is:** Is there a possibility to have the same width for each tick for multiple tables? As in my example the chart with four entries should have less than half the height of the chart with ten entries.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    ytick = data,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 5,
    x tick label style={opacity=0},
    ytick style = {draw=none},
    symbolic y coords = {One, Two, Three, Four}
  ]
  \addplot [fill=gray] coordinates {
    (1,One)
    (3,Two)
    (0,Three)
    (5,Four)
  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    ytick = data,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 5,
    x tick label style={opacity=0},
    ytick style = {draw=none},
    symbolic y coords = {One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten}
  ]
  \addplot [fill=gray] coordinates {
    (4,One)
    (2,Two)
    (1,Three)
    (1,Four)
    (0,Five)
    (5,Six)
    (4,Seven)
    (2,Eight)
    (2,Nine)
    (0,Ten)
  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried working with width and height in the axis options, but that didn't work for charts with three or less entries, because the bars seemed to be above or below the chart.

**Edit for clarification:**

What i want to display is something like that:
[image: Latex Output]

**Some new tries, neither worked:**

I tried the answer of Schrördinger's Cat and added an example of adjusted width and height. But neither delivered a suitable result:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    ytick = data,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 5,
    x tick label style={opacity=0},
    ytick style = {draw=none},
    symbolic y coords = {One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten},
    yticklabels={One, Two}
  ]
  \addplot [fill=gray] coordinates {
    (4,One)
    (2,Two)
    (0,Ten)
  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    ytick = data,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 1,
    x tick label style={opacity=0},
    ytick style = {draw=none},
    symbolic y coords = {One, Two},
    yticklabels={One, Two}
  ]
  \addplot [fill=gray] coordinates {
    (1,One)
    (1,Two)
  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    width = 8.5cm,
    height = 3cm,
    ytick = data,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 1,
    x tick label style={opacity=0},
    ytick style = {draw=none},
    symbolic y coords = {One, Two},
    yticklabels={One, Two}
  ]
  \addplot [fill=gray] coordinates {
    (1,One)
    (1,Two)
  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. I don't quite understand your problem. Can you add a freehand drawing or an explanatory image?

Comment: @AndréC Thank you for your help. I've added an example to the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether or not there is an option to do this automatically. Here, I've done trial and error to set the `heigth=117pt` parameter (207pt by default) and the `enlarge y limits=0.29` parameter. As for the `width=240pt` parameter, I have kept the default value.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    enlarge y limits=0.29,
    height=117pt,width=240pt,
    xbar,
    ytick = data,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 5,
    x tick label style={opacity=0},
    ytick style = {draw=none},
    symbolic y coords = {One, Two, Three, Four}
  ]
  \addplot [fill=gray] coordinates {
    (1,One)
    (3,Two)
    (0,Three)
    (5,Four)
  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%axis equal image=true,
    xbar,
    ytick = data,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 5,
    x tick label style={opacity=0},
    ytick style = {draw=none},
    symbolic y coords = {One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten}
  ]
  \addplot [fill=gray] coordinates {
    (4,One)
    (2,Two)
    (1,Three)
    (1,Four)
    (0,Five)
    (5,Six)
    (4,Seven)
    (2,Eight)
    (2,Nine)
    (0,Ten)
  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks great, thank you. I don't have much charts to do, so I'll go with this one. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! This is a very simple-minded way (but still works).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    ytick = data,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 5,
    x tick label style={opacity=0},
    ytick style = {draw=none},
    symbolic y coords = {One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine,
    Ten},yticklabels={One, Two, Three, Four}
  ]
  \addplot [fill=gray] coordinates {
    (1,One)
    (3,Two)
    (0,Three)
    (5,Four)
    (0,Ten) 
  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    ytick = data,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 5,
    x tick label style={opacity=0},
    ytick style = {draw=none},
    symbolic y coords = {One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten}
  ]
  \addplot [fill=gray] coordinates {
    (4,One)
    (2,Two)
    (1,Three)
    (1,Four)
    (0,Five)
    (5,Six)
    (4,Seven)
    (2,Eight)
    (2,Nine)
    (0,Ten)
  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much. That looks pretty good. Do you know if I can get something like this with the same logic?

![Latex Block](https://imgur.com/a/eWfRpQ3)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [sane_tikz](https://github.com/negrinho/sane_tikz). The code below generates your desired figure.

[image]

```
import sane_tikz as stz
import formatting as fmt

large_data = [4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 5, 4, 2, 2, 0]
large_label_strs = [
    "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine",
    "Ten"
]
small_data = [1, 3, 0, 5]
small_label_strs = large_label_strs[:4]

tick_spacing = 1.0
num_ticks = 5
tick_length = 0.1
rectangle_height = 0.3
rectangle_spacing = 0.2
label_spacing = 0.1
r_fmt = fmt.fill_color('gray')
margin = 0.2

frame_width = num_ticks * tick_spacing
frame_spacing = 1.6
t_fmt = fmt.line_color('gray')


def get_ticks(e):
    top_left_cs, bottom_right_cs = stz.bbox(e)
    bottom_left_cs = stz.bottom_left_coords(top_left_cs, bottom_right_cs)
    top_ticks = []
    bottom_ticks = []
    for i in range(1, num_ticks):
        top_cs = stz.translate_coords_horizontally(top_left_cs,
                                                   i * tick_spacing)
        top_t = stz.vertical_line_segment(top_cs, -tick_length, t_fmt)
        top_ticks.append(top_t)

        bottom_cs = stz.translate_coords_horizontally(bottom_left_cs,
                                                      i * tick_spacing)
        bottom_t = stz.vertical_line_segment(bottom_cs, tick_length, t_fmt)
        bottom_ticks.append(bottom_t)
    return [bottom_ticks, top_ticks]


def bar_plot(data, label_strs):
    cs = [0, 0]
    rs = [
        stz.rectangle_from_width_and_height(cs, rectangle_height, x, r_fmt)
        for x in data
    ]

    stz.distribute_vertically_with_spacing(rs, rectangle_spacing)
    frame_height = (len(data) * rectangle_height +
                    (len(data) - 1) * rectangle_spacing + 2.0 * margin)
    frame = stz.rectangle_from_width_and_height(cs, frame_height, frame_width)
    stz.align_centers_vertically([frame, rs], 0.0)

    labels = []
    for i, r in enumerate(rs):
        l_cs = stz.coords_from_bbox_with_fn(r, stz.left_center_coords)
        l_cs = stz.translate_coords_horizontally(l_cs, -label_spacing)
        l_s = label_strs[i]
        lab = stz.latex(l_cs, l_s, fmt.anchor('right_center'))
        labels.append(lab)

    ticks = get_ticks(frame)
    return [rs, labels, frame, ticks]


e_large = bar_plot(large_data, large_label_strs)
e_small = bar_plot(small_data, small_label_strs)
stz.distribute_horizontally_with_spacing([e_small, e_large], frame_spacing)
stz.align_bottoms([e_large, e_small], 0)

stz.draw_to_tikz_standalone([e_small, e_large], "boxes.tex")
```

Generated tikz code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=gray] (0.000000, 0.500000) -- (1.000000, 0.500000) -- (1.000000, 0.200000) -- (0.000000, 0.200000) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray] (0.000000, 1.000000) -- (3.000000, 1.000000) -- (3.000000, 0.700000) -- (0.000000, 0.700000) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray] (0.000000, 1.500000) -- (0.000000, 1.500000) -- (0.000000, 1.200000) -- (0.000000, 1.200000) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray] (0.000000, 2.000000) -- (5.000000, 2.000000) -- (5.000000, 1.700000) -- (0.000000, 1.700000) -- cycle;
\node[anchor=east] at (-0.100000,0.350000) {One};
\node[anchor=east] at (-0.100000,0.850000) {Two};
\node[anchor=east] at (-0.100000,1.350000) {Three};
\node[anchor=east] at (-0.100000,1.850000) {Four};
\draw[] (0.000000, 2.200000) -- (5.000000, 2.200000) -- (5.000000, 0.000000) -- (0.000000, 0.000000) -- cycle;
\draw[draw=gray] (1.000000, 0.000000) -- (1.000000, 0.100000);
\draw[draw=gray] (2.000000, 0.000000) -- (2.000000, 0.100000);
\draw[draw=gray] (3.000000, 0.000000) -- (3.000000, 0.100000);
\draw[draw=gray] (4.000000, 0.000000) -- (4.000000, 0.100000);
\draw[draw=gray] (1.000000, 2.200000) -- (1.000000, 2.100000);
\draw[draw=gray] (2.000000, 2.200000) -- (2.000000, 2.100000);
\draw[draw=gray] (3.000000, 2.200000) -- (3.000000, 2.100000);
\draw[draw=gray] (4.000000, 2.200000) -- (4.000000, 2.100000);
\draw[fill=gray] (6.700000, 0.500000) -- (10.700000, 0.500000) -- (10.700000, 0.200000) -- (6.700000, 0.200000) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray] (6.700000, 1.000000) -- (8.700000, 1.000000) -- (8.700000, 0.700000) -- (6.700000, 0.700000) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray] (6.700000, 1.500000) -- (7.700000, 1.500000) -- (7.700000, 1.200000) -- (6.700000, 1.200000) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray] (6.700000, 2.000000) -- (7.700000, 2.000000) -- (7.700000, 1.700000) -- (6.700000, 1.700000) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray] (6.700000, 2.500000) -- (6.700000, 2.500000) -- (6.700000, 2.200000) -- (6.700000, 2.200000) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray] (6.700000, 3.000000) -- (11.700000, 3.000000) -- (11.700000, 2.700000) -- (6.700000, 2.700000) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray] (6.700000, 3.500000) -- (10.700000, 3.500000) -- (10.700000, 3.200000) -- (6.700000, 3.200000) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray] (6.700000, 4.000000) -- (8.700000, 4.000000) -- (8.700000, 3.700000) -- (6.700000, 3.700000) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray] (6.700000, 4.500000) -- (8.700000, 4.500000) -- (8.700000, 4.200000) -- (6.700000, 4.200000) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray] (6.700000, 5.000000) -- (6.700000, 5.000000) -- (6.700000, 4.700000) -- (6.700000, 4.700000) -- cycle;
\node[anchor=east] at (6.600000,0.350000) {One};
\node[anchor=east] at (6.600000,0.850000) {Two};
\node[anchor=east] at (6.600000,1.350000) {Three};
\node[anchor=east] at (6.600000,1.850000) {Four};
\node[anchor=east] at (6.600000,2.350000) {Five};
\node[anchor=east] at (6.600000,2.850000) {Six};
\node[anchor=east] at (6.600000,3.350000) {Seven};
\node[anchor=east] at (6.600000,3.850000) {Eight};
\node[anchor=east] at (6.600000,4.350000) {Nine};
\node[anchor=east] at (6.600000,4.850000) {Ten};
\draw[] (6.700000, 5.200000) -- (11.700000, 5.200000) -- (11.700000, 0.000000) -- (6.700000, 0.000000) -- cycle;
\draw[draw=gray] (7.700000, 0.000000) -- (7.700000, 0.100000);
\draw[draw=gray] (8.700000, 0.000000) -- (8.700000, 0.100000);
\draw[draw=gray] (9.700000, 0.000000) -- (9.700000, 0.100000);
\draw[draw=gray] (10.700000, 0.000000) -- (10.700000, 0.100000);
\draw[draw=gray] (7.700000, 5.200000) -- (7.700000, 5.100000);
\draw[draw=gray] (8.700000, 5.200000) -- (8.700000, 5.100000);
\draw[draw=gray] (9.700000, 5.200000) -- (9.700000, 5.100000);
\draw[draw=gray] (10.700000, 5.200000) -- (10.700000, 5.100000);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you @rnegrinho. I'll come back to this solution If I ever have to do more tables. Looks awesome to simply use a script to get the thing done.